# What makes the headphone remote controls compatible or not to an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, audio, microphone, remote-control, ear-phones

What makes the cable headphone remote controls (volume up and down for example) to be compatible or not to an iPhone?
Or, how does the iPhone recognizes and says which headphone works and which doesn't? Is there a microchip or anything?
Thank you!

Comment: are you talking about Bluetooth or cable headphones

Comment: Cable headphones

Comment: OK, thanks, take look at your headphone plug and tell me does it has 4 rings (3 narrow black ones) dividing the plug in to 4 sections.